# Sum column values under condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose this:

Works table

```
Name
created_at
Size
```

I want to list all works and in the end sum up all Size values, but under one condition. created_at must be < 1 year ago.

I know

```
@works.sum(&:size)
```

works but it doesn't filter out the 'created_at' part.

Then i got to this
    @works.sum(&:size, :conditions => ['created_at > ?', 1.year.ago])

But keep getting a compile error about expecting a ) instead of a ,

Help please? Any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use **scope** to keep the model clean

```
#controller
class WorksController < ApplicationsController

  def index
    @works.recent.sum(&:size)
  end
end

#model
class Work
 scope :recent, ->{ where('created_at > ?', 1.year.ago) }
end
```

Comment: @Joel, is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@works.where('created_at > ?', 1_year_ago).sum(:size)
```